# Combination of JavaFX User Interface and Client-Server-Application; Issue with connecting client to server along many other things

Tags: java, javafx, client-server

1. Problem: Client won't connect to Server anymore.
2. I need the different objects of the UI, that are initialized in the start-Method of my Application class in my main. How do I pass them to the main?

Complete Background:
My goal with this whole Application is to create a little game that multiple people can play. It will be really simple with a few buttons and Labels and in the end there should also be a way for the players to interact. I also want this game to be accessed via a server, with every player having an Account, consisting of username and Password.
As I am new to Java-Programming, I know that is - at the moment - completely out of my league. But I am trying little by little to learn everything I need in order to get there.

The important part:
I managed to connect server and client locally with the UI, but couldn't get my program to create Accounts, which should be stored in my "AccountDatabase". This resulted in no-one being able to successfully "log in" (log in is here simulated by displaying the message "log in succesfull!")
Tried to fix that, discovered I needed to use threads in order for multiple clients and rewrote my code almost completely. Now I can't even connect a client to the server...
I have tried so many things and rewrote so much of the code that I don't know what is going wrong anymore. I would be extremely grateful if someone here could take a look at my probably super messy code to see what I need to do here.

Code of my main class:

public class Main extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    LoginUI loginUI = new LoginUI(primaryStage);
    loginUI.setScene(primaryStage, loginUI.getScene());
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    InetAddress ip = null;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Client client = new Client(ip, 9376);
    loginUI.getSignUpUI().setSignUpButtonAction(client);
    //how do I get the instance of LoginUI instantiated in the start-Method?
}
```

}

Expected result:
Client connects to Server, UI (LoginUI) shows up with a Hyperlink that redirects to (SignUpUI). This scene should let the user enter Username and Password, check "AccountDataBase" for already existing Accounts with that Username and finally create the Account if possible. Back in the (LoginUI) the user should also be able to enter Username and Password, which get compared to Account-Data in my "AccountDataBase" and let the User log in.

Actual Results:
Client won't connect to server after rewriting code to use threads. The farthest I've gotten is to establish a connection, but failing to creating new Accounts, as the user-inputted Account-Date were probably not stored in the AccountDataBase...

If you have made it this far, you'll probably need to see code of the others classes I've written. I just haven't posted them bc Stackoverflow told me not to post whole files... Feel free to let me know, if you need any more of the Code!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you succesfully entering the methods? Are they sequential calls? Are they not getting called at all?

Comment: @Akin Okegbile: If I don't remove the last line in the main-Method I get the following error: Error:(27, 9) java: cannot find symbol: variable loginUI. I guess that is to be expected, since the main-Method doesn't know of the existence of loginUI. My issue here is that I don't know how to pass the instance of loginUI over to the main-method. If I remove the last line of code from the main-Method, I don't get any error at all, UI loads up fine but the client does not connect to the server (this is a separate issue to the not being able to pass the instance of loginUI to the main)

Comment: move the LoginUi to be a memeber of the Main class and not just a method variable.

Comment: @mavriksc This would mean that I'd have to declare a new Stage-Object along with a new LoginUI-Object in the main-method. Would that not be an issue? FYI: The code still compiles and the UI shows up if I do that, but does it mess anything up internally having 2 stages?

Comment: my code below is no different from yours except that you can reference the UI created in start from other methods in your main class

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
public class Main extends Application {
    LoginUI loginUI
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    loginUI = new LoginUI(primaryStage);
    loginUI.setScene(primaryStage, loginUI.getScene());
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
InetAddress ip = null;
try {
    ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Client client = new Client(ip, 9376);
loginUI.getSignUpUI().setSignUpButtonAction(client);
//how do I get the instance of LoginUI instantiated in the start-Method?
}
}
```

Comment: by doing that I get a the error-message that a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context :( I could of course make that member static, but would that result in any issues down the line?

Comment: OK... i missed that you are trying to do stuff in main other than launch(args).... With JavaFX once you call that you can do some other set up in start()like create events listeners and attach to buttons or set up connections to services. but nothing else in Main method... i created a pretty simple FX Client recently maybe it will hlep https://github.com/mavriksc/FxClient/tree/master/src/main/java/org/mavriksc/lol/fxclient

Comment: thank you so much, I'll gladly take a look at that! :)

Comment: actually if you want less frameworks and just doing things from the Application class this may be more usefull https://github.com/mavriksc/chessbook/blob/master/src/main/java/chessbook/ChessBookFX.java

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed, and why.